# GROUP BY on column alias with NULLs returns incorrect result in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Let's assume you have a column that contains 1s, 0s and NULLs. You want to group by only 1 and 0 and count NULL as 0, giving you only two and not three rows in the result set:

```
SELECT SUM(aTable.whatever),IFNULL(aNullableTable.NullableColumn,0) AS TRUEORFALSE FROM aTable LEFT JOIN aNullableTable ON aTable.ID = aNullableTable.ID GROUP BY TRUEORFALSE;
```

In my world this should be equivalent to:

```
SELECT SUM(aTable.whatever),IFNULL(aNullableTable.NullableColumn,0) AS TRUEORFALSE FROM aTable LEFT JOIN aNullableTable ON aTable.ID = aNullableTable.ID GROUP BY IFNULL(aNullableTable.NullableColumn,0);
```

However, it is not. The first example may return three rows if there are NULLs in the column. The second example correctly groups NULL as 0.

Am I misunderstanding something here or is this a bug?

It should be noted that the behavior is similar if replacing IFNULL with something like:

`IF(NullableColumn IS NULL,0,1)`, `IF(NullableColumn<1,0,1)` and `IF(NullableColumn IS NOT NULL,1,0)`

Observed on MySQL 5.7.11

Edit: Perhaps I should add that this is when LEFT JOIN'ing another table where the NULL values come in. I just edited the example.

Edit: Turns out it was because I had used `SELECT IFNULL(NullableColumn,0) AS NullableColumn GROUP BY NullableColumn;` This is not a good idea, for future reference, and will give a very confusing result. In the above example you'd get two rows with 0 and one with 1, instead of NULL, 0 and 1 as expected if the GROUP BY actually did not work properly. Silly me.

Comment: IFNULL() has only 2 parameters and not 3

Comment: Oh, yeah, right. Sorry. I'll just correct that. Obviously it's correct in my tested code.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c57094/2 Could you show the error in that demo?

Comment: I can't - it's MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Changed description to use left join, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this could occur if `TRUEORFALSE` is a column in a table in the `FROM` clause.

The SQL standard does not allow for the use of column aliases in the `GROUP BY`.  Hence, if a name is encountered that is a column name, then that should be the first definition for it.  Then, if no matching column is found, MySQL can look for a column alias.

Comment: TRUEORFALSE is not a column in the table. Also, where do you get that we cannot use an alias in group by? I belive juergen just posted an SQL fiddle that shows this is very possible. Also I use it other places (just not with NULL columns) where it's perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm sorry. This was correct. I just tried hunting down the error (I had corrected it so I had to reconstruct it for the purpose of this post) and it turns out the "AS [existingTableName]" actually was the problem. It does not override but rather does a GROUP BY *while still* changing the NULL to 0, which is kind of confusing - you'd get two rows with 0 and one with 1, instead of NULL, 0 and 1.

Comment: Still confused about this though: "The SQL standard does not allow for the use of column aliases in the GROUP BY".

Comment: @nickdnk . . . A column alias is a name assigned in the `SELECT`.  These are not permitted in the `GROUP BY` in many databases.